# Directionally derivative $\lim_{t\searrow 0}\frac{(x+th)(\omega)-x(\omega)}{t}$ for $x\in C(\Omega)$

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives

Let $C(\Omega)$ be the space of continuous functions over a compact metric space $\Omega$. We fix $\omega \in \Omega$, what is the directionally differentiable at $x\in C(\Omega)$? More specifically, what is the meaning of direction $h$ when we talk about $h$ in function space, i.e. $x+th \in C(\Omega),\forall t\in [0,1]$. According to the definition of directionally differentiable, we have $\lim_{t\searrow 0}\frac{(x+th)(\omega)-x(\omega)}{t}$ exist. What is the limit? My conjecture is $h(\omega)$.

Comment: I think you are confused about something.  Normally one would speak of the directional derivative of a function _on_ $C(\Omega)$ not of an element $x\in C(\Omega)$.  The limit you've written is trivially equal to $h(\omega)$ since $(x+th)(\omega)$ means $x(\omega)+th(\omega)$ by definition.

Comment: @EricWofsey Hello, I think we should consider in this way, fixed $\omega$, we consider the function $\omega(x)(:=x(\omega),x\in C(\Omega))$. Now I want to analyze the directional derivative of $\omega(x),x\in C(\Omega)$. What is the limit $\lim_{t \searrow 0} \frac{\omega(x+th)-\omega(x)}{t}$